# Ubuntu 19.10 takes 192 seconds to load

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 19.10

I would like to request help with a slowly booting Ubuntu. I have a HP pavillion laptop with a 250gb ssd with Windows 10 installed, and run Ubuntu from an external harddrive. I have recently fixed some problems I had with dual boot in UEFI mode, but now my next problem (which already existed while I was trying to solve dual-boot problems and is not the result of whatever I fixed) is that Ubuntu takes about 192 seconds to load.

External harddrive is a seagate backup plus 4tb read/write speed of about 110/120mbps connected with a USB 3.0.

I am not sure how to fix it, but I have the outputs from systemd-analyze critical-chain and blame, as well as dmesg.

From dmesg it seems there is some time taken to mount 'sdb8' at around 43 seconds and possibly the bluetooth delays from 60-140 seconds. According to the systemd-analyze plot there seems to be a long delay between sysinit.target and the nss-lookup.target.

However, I am no expert with this and I am not sure how to interpret these outputs, and so would request some help in what to do about it.

Thanks!
:

[dmesg output](https://gist.github.com/ogola89/d0b768c7f87079c998b7adbdeec86226#file-dmesg_output-txt)

[systemd-analyze critical-chain output](https://gist.github.com/ogola89/d0b768c7f87079c998b7adbdeec86226#file-systemd_critical_chain-txt)

[systemd-analyze blame output](https://gist.github.com/ogola89/d0b768c7f87079c998b7adbdeec86226#file-systemd_blame-txt)

[Here is the output from the systemd-analyze plot](https://ibb.co/jHWrcMs)

Comment: The most likely cause is whatever you 'fixed'.  If you removed any partitions, is your system waiting for them? (thus timeouts), or if you renamed/changed partitions did the UUID change thus you need to change the fstab to reflect this or other change. You can view block devices with `blkid` which will give you UUIDs, and compare with `/etc/fstab` etc as the system will wait for any not there for some time, making boot slow...  (sorry I didn't look at your posts, general info only)

Comment: Can you add to question speed of hard drive and if connected by USB 2 or 3 or other connection.  System does seem slow even with a slow external.

Comment: 17 seconds to flush journals - they must have been *enormous*! This implies that you have a lot of problems or errors logged that you should look into fixing.

Comment: @user535733 how would I look into fixing them? I am unfamiliar with the journals

Comment: @guiverc I have edited to mention that the slow speed was from before fixing the problem with bootup

Comment: @crip659 I have added the HD info 110/120 r/w speed via USB 3.0

Comment: @Ogola89 - for separate or branching questions ("*how do I review my logs?*"), try the search box at the top of the page. The AskUbuntu format is one question, several answers. It's not a forum or conversation. There are other official support venues, like Ubuntuforums.org, that do one-on-one conversational tutoring.

Comment: Is the external HDD on a USB 3 port? If the socket on the PC is not red or blue, it's probably not USB 3 which would definately slow you down.